# Validating Jquery autocomplete field using jquery validation plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, jquery-validate

I am not so good with jquery and hence need your help.

I have a form in which there are two fields "origin" and "destination". So I am using the jquery autocomplete for both the fields.

```
$('#form1_origin,#form1_destination').autocomplete({
        lookup: countriesArray,
        minChars: 0,
    });
```

It works great but when I am trying to validate these fields using jquery validation plugin, I get some problems.

Here is the code:-

```
$('#form_1').validate({
    errorClass: "airError",
    focusInvalid: true,
    success: function(element){
        $(element).closest('.airError').removeClass('.airError');
    },
    errorPlacement: function(error,element){
        if(element.attr("name") === "form1_infant" || element.attr("name") === "form1_departure"){
            error.insertAfter('#showErrors');
        }else{
            error.insertAfter(element);
        }
    },
    rules: {
    form1_origin: {
        validSelectionOrigin: true,
    },
    form1_destination:{
        validSelectionDestination: true,
        compare_origin_dest: true
    },
    // rules for  rest of the fields
    },
});
```

**Problem:-**

As I am pretty sure that jquery validates the fields on **onkeyup**. So If I **TYPE** the value in this field, it works fine but when I select the value from the autocomplete list, It does not validate the field as I can still see the error being displayed. So what can i do to make it work for both ??

Comment: Can you please tell the plugin which you are using for validation?

Comment: Try adding:

    onclick: true

Inside .validate

Comment: please provide link to your site , or jsfiddle

Comment: @AbhasTandon, Clearly `onclick` has nothing to do with this question.  The `onclick` option is only for `radio` and `checkbox` elements and `true` is already the default.  Please refer to the documentation before spreading misinformation:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate#onclick

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Quote OP:**

> *"As I am pretty sure that jquery validates the fields on `onkeyup`. So If I TYPE the value in this field, it works fine but when I select the value from the autocomplete list, It does not validate the field as I can still see the error being displayed. So what can i do to make it work for both?"*

The jQuery Validate plugin evaluates text `input` elements by several triggers... key-up, blur, and submit button click (all fields at once).

The jQuery Validate plugin also provides you with the `.valid()` method where you can trigger validation programatically.

I don't think you've shown enough relevant code, but basically, you'll need to trigger `.valid()` whenever the value of the field changes.

Adjust code as required...

```
$('input[name="autocompletedField]').on('change', function() {
    $(this).valid();  // trigger validation test
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var validation;
$("#term").autocomplete({
    source: 'search_product.php',
    change: function(event, ui) {
        if (!ui.item) {
            this.value = '';
            validation = false;
            console.log(validation)
        } else {
            validation = true;
            console.log(validation)
        }
    }
});
   
$('.validation').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    
    if (validation) {
        this.submit();
    }{
        alert('Неправильне введення')
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).